# Como alterar a aparência do formulário de acordo com o sistema operacional?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows

Quando desenvolvo um projeto no C# (Windows Form Application) a aparência da janela da aplicação (bordas) fica de acordo com a do SO no qual estou rodando a aplicação (Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10)!

#### WINDOWS XP

[image: Formato Windows XP]

#### WINDOWS 7

[image: Formato Windows 7]

Teria como eu rodar o meu programa no meu Windows 10 no Visual Studio e ver como as bordas do programa ficariam no Windows 7 por exemplo?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Pode existir alguma ferramenta, com grande probabilidade de ser *online*, mas eu desconheço. Oficial não tem nada até porque é complicado sem que o sistema operacional ajude.

Mesmo assim ainda é complicado porque você deve estar imaginando que todo mundo usa com o tema padrão do Windows, mas muitas pessoas não usam, então você não tem como ver todas possibilidades. Se sua aplicação depende do tema para ficar bom provavelmente tem algo errada com ela.

Claro que você pode desenvolver uma aplicação que faça isso em máquinas virtuais e coordene a apresentação dos principais temas. Mas se fizer, provavelmente tem um produto na mão.

Answer (score 2):

Eu desconheço isto, o que você pode fazer para contornar este problema é remover as bordas do seu formulario e deixar imagens de fundo, ou seja, você mesmo vai criar a imagem de sua tela e setar como background-image.

Comment: também  concordo ele pode remover as boras e criar bordas e botões para fechar e miniminar para que o layout seja sempre  o  mesmo  em  todas as versões compativeis com  o donetframwork  que ele utiliza

Comment: Eu já estava fazendo isso, acontece que aí o usuário não pode redimensionar a janela! (deixei o FormBorderStyle como NONE) e o usuário, nessa minha aplicação que eu tô construindo, ele tem que poder alterar o tamanho da janela! Só que se eu deixar com as bordas do Windows a aplicação fica meio feia (no Windows 7, Vista e Xp) já no Windows 8 e 10 fica melhorzinho!